# Business Rule in ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to respect this Business Rule: Set EXPIRATION_DATE NULL if the TENANT is an OWNER of the APARTMENT. EXPIRATION_DATE indicates the expiry date of a rental contract

- TENANT (COD_T, EXPIRATION_DATE, COD_APARTMENT) --where the tenant is living
- OWNER (COD_O, COD_APARTMENT)  --apartments that belong to the owner
- APARTMENT (COD_APARTMENT)

I'd like to know: if I use this script and the CHECK became true, it will set automatically EXPIRATION_DATE to NULL?
If not, how can I do it?

`CREATE TABLE TENANT(
 COD_T CHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY,
 COD_APARTMENT INT REFERENCES APARTMENT(COD_APARTMENT),
 EXPIRATION_DATE DATE
 (CHECK (COD_T IN ( SELECT COD_O -- same type COD_T
                   FROM OWNER O
                   WHERE COD_APARTMENT = O.CODAPARTMENT
                 )
        )

 AND EXPIRATION_DATE IS NULL
);`

Comment: @Uomelepre . . . A check constraint cannot reference another table.  You either need a trigger, a user-defined function, or a way of storing all the information in the same row.

Comment: If this were a data model review I would push back strongly about representing an OWNER as a TENANT.

Comment: what you require is called SQL Assertions https://community.oracle.com/ideas/13028

Comment: Thank you to everyone, both of answers and comments were pretty good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a view do get the data in your required check constraint format

```
   CREATE OR replace VIEW tenant_vw
    AS
      SELECT cod_t,
             cod_apartment,
             CASE
               WHEN cod_t IN (SELECT cod_o -- same type COD_T
                              FROM   owner O
                              WHERE  cod_apartment = O.codapartment) THEN NULL
               ELSE expiration_date
             END AS EXPIRATION_DATE
      FROM   tenant;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `view` for such requirement but if you want your data to be updated like this then you need to create the `trigger` as follows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_TENANT 
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON TENANT
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    CNT   NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(1)
      INTO CNT
      FROM OWNER O
     WHERE O.CODAPARTMENT = :NEW.COD_APARTMENT
       AND O.COD_O = :NEW.COD_T;

    IF CNT > 0 THEN
        :NEW.EXPIRATION_DATE := NULL;
    END IF;
END;
/
```